# Changing mime-type for .xml.gz in Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, gzip, mime-types, content-type

I need to fetch xml gzip compressed data files from Javascript (JQuery), and I'd like the browser to automatically decompress them before passing them to JS.

As far as I know, this can be accomplished if the server returns the file with `content-type: text/html` and `content-encoding x-gzip.`

Currently, Tomcat returns .xml.gz files as `Content-Type:application/x-gzip`, what should I do to get my files with the correct header?

I tried to add to the web.xml file:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>xml.gz</extension>
  <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add the XML mime type to the `gz` extension:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>gz</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**References**

- [Multi-Store web.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-slide/Multi_Store_Web.XML)
- [Tomcat Source: trunk/conf/web.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.0.x/trunk/conf/web.xml)